# Calculating Mutual Information between features in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression, binning

I need to calculate the mutual information between various features for designing a classification model using logistic regression. I am facing following problems:

1. I need to divide my data into n bins having approximately equal number of samples. How can I achieve this in Matlab?
2. Should I perform the above discretization on raw data or normalized data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is similar to cross validation, in Matlab you can use the function [crossvalind](http://au.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html) that allow you to split your dataset.

I added the example shown on the page for splitting your data into 10 bins (called 10-fold cross validation).

```
load fisheriris 
indices = crossvalind('Kfold',species,10);
cp = classperf(species);
for i = 1:10
    test = (indices == i); train = ~test;
    class = classify(meas(test,:),meas(train,:),species(train,:));
    classperf(cp,class,test)
end
cp.ErrorRate

ans =

    0.0200
```

You should do this operation after doing the pre-processing of your data (normalisation / standardisation).

Comment: Do i need to sort the data in a particular feature (Column) before applying cross validation? I want n equal density bins with approximately equal samples in each bin. I did normalization->sort->divided the vector into 10 bins but the values for a feature are not equally divided into bins.

Comment: I would rather randomize the order of the sample rather than sorting it. And yeah the size of each bin will be similar.